# Find the max distance at least one of 6 cars can cover if each car can cover 1000km and cars can recharge each other's batteries

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

These are electric cars.

Edit: The efficient approach would take symmetry into account as shown by @R. J. Mathar

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried, efficient or not. Another question - what do you think the answer would be in the simplest case (2 cars)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_problem for the generic problem. This here is the "cars across the desert problem" in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least one simple symmetric solution (not necessarily the maximum, but optimization problems often have extrema at the symmetric choices): Let all 6 cars drive from the initial point (all range 1000) by 1000/6 so their remaining range is down to $5\times 1000/6$. Recharge 5 of the cars equally with the power of the 6th (the 6th is halted there) so we have 5 cars at distance 1000/6 from the origin with range 1000 left. After another distance 1000/5 recharge 4 of the cars with the power of the 5th and this leaves 4 cars at distance 1000/6+1000/5 with range 1000 left. Recursively ... the last car can reach $1000/6+1000/5+1000/4+1000/3+1000/2+1000 = 1000\times 49/20 = 2450$.

Comment: This is clearly the intended solution.  You can think of it as draining the first battery as quickly as possible so that car drives as little as possible.  It should be the maximum, not minimum.

Comment: I came up with the exact same approach after trying a bit more, thanks for confirming!